# Name Interface conventions when name already start with capitalized letter

Tags: interface, naming-conventions

Let say I want to create an interface for a class that should be name JQuery.

If this class is an interface, from the conventions, I should name it IJQuery, but I find it's made the name look weird.

What you think ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most naming conventions "look weird" when compared to written language.  But consistently following a convention pays off in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

I've never been a big fan of embedding information of the type of an object into its name, so I would not use `I` as a prefix anyway. But if you are doing it is a good idea to keep with the convention, but based on your example I would also consider how you name your interfaces, because from what I can tell you would have an `IJQuery` and a `JQueryImpl`.

I would consider naming your interface something like `JavaScriptLibrary` and then name your implementing class `JQuery` or `Prototype`.

In Java:

```
public interface JavaScriptLibrary { ... }

public class JQuery implements JavaScriptLibrary { ... }

public class Prototype implements JavaScriptLibrary { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ponzao has a good point and I tend to not embed type information into the names of classes, variables, etc.  However, when dealing with more than a few files I have found marking interfaces to be helpful.

I use two naming conventions that have been very helpful in past:

**1) m_variableName**

**m_** stands out in the code, marking member variables.

**2) IThisIsAnInterface**

For interfaces you might consider something like I_JQuery with the **I_** marking your interface.